# SourceLink - Stepping into async base class method not working

Tags: c#, sourcelink

In my NuGet Package where SourceLink is enabled and working I have a `ServiceBase` class which contains async methods for Get, Post, Update etc.

Stepping into the constructor of the base class works fine, also stepping into any synchronous methods.

If I call the Get method like this:

```
var hotel = await Get<Car>(new Uri("http://cars/api/car/1"));
```

I am not able to step into that method. (Where the implementation of `async Task <T> Get<T>` is inside the base class.)

This only occurs if the NuGet Package is built in release mode. Is this a optimization effect?

Comment: If it's built in Release mode you won't have the debugging information. You can only really debug when built in Debug mode.

Comment: @RobSedgwick, Release builds have optimizations that Debug builds don't have. Debug builds also have a lot of `nop` instructions in order for us to put breakpoints on curly braces and other places. But Release build can have debugging information. I always deploy pdbs with my release builds.

Comment: @Matteo, are you packaging the pdbs when building in Release mode?